# Razor Foreach model list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

what I'm trying to do is display each item in a list on a razor page:

_layout.cshtml

```
<div id="LeftSidebar">
    <ul>
        @foreach (var x in MenuItems.Items)
        {
            <li><a href="#">@x.ItemName </a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

menu.cs

```
public class Menu
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public string Alt { get; set; }

    public Menu()
    {

    }

    public Menu(string itemName, string alt)
    {
        ItemName = itemName;
        Alt = alt;
    }

}

public class MenuItems
{
    public static List<Menu> Items = new List<Menu>();
    public MenuItems()
    {
        Items.Add(new Menu
           {
               Alt = "test item",
               ItemName = "item 1",
           });
        Items.Add(new Menu
        {
            Alt = "test item",
            ItemName = "item 2",
        });
    }
}
```

thats what i have so far but it doesn't display anything?

Thanks
Houlahan

Comment: You didn't post the controller/action...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are never creating an instance of the MenuItems class as your just accessing a static field in the class - therefore the constructor isn't running and adding the two test items.

Try replacing the MenuItems constructor with a static constructor:

```
public class MenuItems
{
    public static List<Menu> Items;

    static MenuItems()
    {
       Items = new List<Menu>();

       Items.Add(new Menu
       {
           Alt = "test item",
           ItemName = "item 1",
       });
       Items.Add(new Menu
       {
            Alt = "test item",
            ItemName = "item 2",
        });
     }
}
```

This should ensure the Items field is filled when you access it using MenuItems.Items.

Comment: im not sure how i would do that (I'm pretty new to MVC3&razor) would i have to make a partial view? and then call the controller?

Comment: You could add a static constructor I guess.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the above pattern then just replace the MenuItems constructor with a static constructor -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: what i used was  @Html.Partial("Menu", MenuItems.Items) and then <ul>
            @foreach (var x in MenuItems.Items)
            {
                <li><a href="#">@x.ItemName </a></li>
            }
        </ul> in the partial view but that didn't work ether

Comment: Please see the edit I've just made the original answer. The above when dropped into the code you originally posted should make this work.